# Color correcting software for Windows (system-wide, software-based color calibration?)

Tags: windows, drivers, colors, calibration

Are there any system-wide, manual color correcting/calibrating programs for Windows?  Software that allows you to adjust colors with more control and precision than you get with most ATI/NVIDIA display drivers?

I find that some of the ATI/NVIDIA drivers, perhaps for older graphics cards, lack enough control to really allow an accurate match with printed output.  I was wondering if there's a non-proprietary color correction program that might provide the level of control that I'm needing, without having to buy new hardware?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose by "non-proprietary" you mean not distributed by a GPU manufacturer.

In this case, take a look at **[Powerstrip](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)**. It works its magic for pretty much any graphics card and monitor and any version of Windows (since 95), most certainly the best program of its kind, by a far cry.

> A simple menu that pops up from the
>   system tray provides **access to some
>   500 controls** over your display
>   hardware, including **sophisticated
>   color correction tools**.

[image]

*Powerstrip is shareware, try before you buy.*